# loading symbol for answers is too big

Tags: discussion, android-app

*"Pull to refresh"* for both question and Answers are different.  There is no issue in showing different loading symbols but why it is totally different?

[image]

Shall we have a common "Pull to refresh" type of loading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The smaller indicator is the pull to refresh indicator, you're seeing it because you're pulling down on the screen.

The big loading indicator you're seeing is the empty state for the answers list. It shows when the initial load of answers hasn't been completed or when the answers are being parsed from the API.

They serve two different purposes, and it makes sense for one of them to display when there's content on the page but it doesn't make sense for the other (the bigger one) to display when there's content on the page because it's in the midst of entirely changing that content.

Answer (score 1):

Pull-To-Refresh is mainly for pulling down ListView/GridView or any view to get latest data, which will be added up at top along with old data.

But here StackExchange does a hack for implementing Pull-To-Refresh technique in Answers section. It more looks like a **normal refresh** in Answers section, but it looks perfect Pull-To-Refresh in Questions section.